# Swift: How to take screenshot of hidden window of external application

Tags: swift, macos

I have tried the following code:

windowNumber is CGWindowID

```
func screenshot(imgOption:CGWindowImageOption = .bestResolution ) -> NSImage {
    guard let winNumber = self.windowNumber else { return NSImage( size: NSSize(width: 1, height: 1)) }

    let inf = CGFloat(FP_INFINITE)
    let null = CGRect(x: inf, y: inf, width: 0, height: 0)

    let cgImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(null, .optionIncludingWindow, CGWindowID(winNumber), imgOption)

    //cgImage == nil

    guard let cgImageUnwrapped = cgImage else { return NSImage() }

    let image = NSImage(cgImage: cgImageUnwrapped, size: self.frame.value.size )

    return image
}
```

but with the following code I have a nil result in case of window is hidden.